# What is the use of "SELECT <somevalue>" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql allows just do a "select 1" and will return column/value of "1". Also if I provide some random string.

```
mysql> select "foo" ;
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Is there any use-case for supporting these commands?

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely use cases where this feature comes in handy.  Support you had a table of grades and students, which looked something like this:

```
Student | Grade
Tom     |  75
Tim     |  85
Paul    |  50
Mark    |  65
Beth    |  70
John    |  80
Dan     |  55
```

If you were tasked with creating a report which showed all students, and whether they passed or fail, you could use the select constant feature.  Let's say that a failing grade was anything below `60`.  But you have one problem, namely that the label `Pass` or `Fail` does not actually appear in your table.  You can write the following query:

```
SELECT Student,
       CASE WHEN Grade < 60 THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass' END AS Result
From students
```

This would give the following output:

```
Student | Result
Tom     |  Pass
Tim     |  Pass       -- these constants are not part of your original data
Paul    |  Fail       -- set, but rather were introduced in the SELECT statement
Mark    |  Pass
Beth    |  Pass
John    |  Pass
Dan     |  Fail
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found out that this is useful for checking connection to the server. Wonder if there are any other uses.

Comment: This should be a comment, or better yet, added to your original question.